# Why does my Mathilda hydrangea have an old green flower and a new purple one on the same stem?

Tags: indoors, containers, hydrangea

Hydrangeas are my favorite flowers. I only have one potted Mathilda gutges plant in my condo. I don't know much about their care. The plant had three flowers. It was dying and I cut two of them because they looked really bad. One survived and it's still on the plant. It's humid to the touch and alive but green in color.

I'm watering it and I noticed it has new purple flowers on the same stem. Should I cut the green flower? Should I leave the plant alone? It's September and I thought there wouldn't be any more flowers for the rest of the year, so this is a nice surprise.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hydrangea is also my favorite! Yours looks really good for an indoor hydrangea. I have many varieties growing outdoors and occasionally have bushes pop up errant color flowers, like yours. This happens more with the newer varieties I planted, and is possibly due to its genetics from hybridizing and cross breeding. Leave the blue flower, it is interesting looking! I have not had any problem with leaving them, nor have the errant color flowers increased. Most just show for the one season.